How to fix or get rid of BadDLLP warnings (Correctable PCIe Bus Error) flooding my logs?
First off, this question is not a duplicate of Why is journalctl reporting "PCIe Bus Error" BadTLP and BadDLLP? because instead of asking what is causing this kernel warning, I directly ask how to solve it, or do some work-around.
In something about a straight hour of writing and then reading from/to my newly connected USB disk device Crucial P3 PCIe 3.0 x4 NVMe M.2 2280 SSD of size 4TB with model number CT4000P3SSD8, which I have put inside an AXAGON EEM2-SG2 SuperSpeed+ USB-C M.2 disk enclosure, and connected it to a Thunderbolt 3 USB-C connector in my oldish Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming 7577 laptop.
I immediatelly noticed such BadDLLP warnings (Correctable PCIe Bus Error) as this one (the time was removed for short):
kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:02:00.0
kernel: pcieport 0000:02:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
kernel: pcieport 0000:02:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
kernel: pcieport 0000:02:00.0:    [ 7] BadDLLP

In just about an hour, kernel generated almost 300,000 of these warnings/correctable errors:
# journalctl --boot -1 --no-pager --no-hostname | grep BadDLLP | wc --lines

292727

Is there anything I can do with relative safey to mitigate these warnings/correctable errors?

OS: Linux Mint 22 (wilma) with kernel version 6.8.0-51-generic.

(Before, this answer used to suggest pcie_ecrc=off, but on further examination it seems to not just disable error reporting in Linux kernel, but it actually tells the hardware to ignore errors, which might cause problems on its own.)
pcie_aspm=off disables much of PCIe power management. You might not care about that on a desktop, but on a laptop it might be important, not only to limit power consumption, but also keep the heat generation within manageable limits. The cooling solutions on laptops tend to not be quite as effective as on desktops and servers, for obvious reasons.
pci=noaer might be a better option, as it turns off just the error reporting part. The hardware will still follow the default error correction policy as set by the system firmware (BIOS or UEFI), but the Correctable PCIe Bus Error messages should no longer be generated.
If the pcie_aspm=off helps, it might mean some hardware component is not fully obeying the PCIe power management states and is generating error messages about random interference on a PCIe link whose other endpoint is currently powered down. In that case, a bug report might be appropriate so that the root cause can be properly fixed.
The device 8086:15da mentioned in the error message seems to be the Intel JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 bridge, so perhaps there is something that could be done in the Thunderbolt driver to eliminate or limit the torrent of "correctable PCIe error" messages.
There is also the possibility that the error messages indicate a bad Thunderbolt cable or a dirty or damaged connector. But I suppose you've already checked for that.

Disabling ASPM (Active-State Power Management) (Wikipedia link) globally via GRUB kernel parameter pcie_aspm=off (RedHat docs link) appears to resolve the issue.
The Kernel docs on pcie_aspm (link), excerpt:
pcie_aspm=      [PCIE] Forcibly enable or disable PCIe Active State Power
        Management.
        off     Disable ASPM.
        force   Enable ASPM even on devices that claim not to support it.
        WARNING: Forcing ASPM on may cause system lockups.


Disclaimer: I suspect, that this option disables all PCIe power-savings, so it I post it just until I know more options, for example if it is possible to turn off power-saving strictly only for this device...
